# Microsoft Reporting Services how to create dynamic headers

Tags: reporting-services, header

I want to setup a dynamic header which should look different on the following pages. I tried to setup a page counter with a simple function in the header which increments a public var.

But when using a filter to determine the page number, it's not working. Only the first result is leading and from what I understood so far is that the first result is just copied onto the following pages. All functions within the header element are only executed once and copied afterwards.

does anybody know workaround to solve the problem?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5pFI.png)

Comment: It is not clear if the example you have in your link is a demonstration of the desired result or the problematic output.  When you say that you are 'using a filter to determine the page number' what do you mean by this?

Comment: I increment a counter every time the column header is printed. And then i want to hide some elements within the header but only if it isn't the first page. But this isn't possible the way I did it because only the first result counts and is just copied to all other pages. The First result is ---> Page = 1 then print element endif. This query isn't triggered on the other pages.  I hope u know understand what I mean and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you have set all three fields(Invoice, Customer, Agent) in the header of the Report. Simply move the two fields(Customer, Agent)  you don't want in the body, at the top before the start for your table.

As I literally just used it, I would like to add, that if you are in the header you can do the following in the Hidden Expression:

Hide on first page:

```
=(Globals!PageNumber = 1)
```

Hide on last page:

```
=(Globals!PageNumber = Globals!OverallTotalPages)
```

Hide on first and last page:

```
=(Globals!PageNumber = 1) OR (Globals!PageNumber = Globals!OverallTotalPages)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't solve my problem. You can't use these Global Vars in the Body Area. And even if I could the header (which is just a body element with RepeatOnNewPage=true / column heading may a better description for it) is just copied to the following pages. And Putting all my data in the header isn't a viable option

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the report? You could always introduce your own pageNumber variable (setting it in the header and retrieving in the body).